# Como trabalhar com Log em Java?

Tags: java, log

Eu preciso fazer uma condição baseada no Log do meu projeto Java.

Ex:

```
Enquanto(TextoDoLog == "PalavraTal"){
    faça algo;
}
```

Mas não sei se tenho que criar alguma classe, ou método, como manusear isso.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito aberta. O que você está chamando de "Log" nesse contexto? De onde que ele vem? O que faz ele mudar?

Comment: Eu to trabalhando com Iniciar, Limpar(excluir), Migrar e Informar os metadados de um banco... Log é a descrição do que está acontecendo durante a execução 
Ex: Downloading... Executing...INFO..Finished  
Essas coisas

Comment: Você já está usando algo para armazenar as etapas do log? Uma variável ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Ai que tá..
private static final Logger logMigrations = Logger.getLogger(ComandoInit.class.getName());
é o que está sendo declarado no inicio da classe. Mas não sei se já posso usá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

O Java possui [alguns frameworks](https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-java-logging-frameworks/) de *logging*, sendo o [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) o mais famoso deles.

Como todo framework, é necessária uma prévia configuração para que possa utilizá-lo, mas no caso do Log4j é bem simples.

---

Uma vez configurado, você pode "loggar" sua aplicação apenas com as chamadas de métodos como as abaixo:

- `logger.error("Ocorreu um erro aqui");`
- `logger.warn("Atenção!");`
- `logger.info("Informação :P");`

Dentre outros...

---

Com o Log4j você pode configurar como o log será armazenado: se será apenas exibido no console do servidor, se vai salvar num arquivo a parte e etc.

Inclusive, você pode formatar como o log é armazenado, incluindo o nível (erro, info, warn, debug e etc), data, hora, a **classe** e até o **método** onde o log foi criado.

---

[Aqui](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/apendice-logging-com-log4j/) tem um tutorial de como configurar e usar o Log4j.